# regex for parsing italic text?

Tags: php, regex, parsing, italic

Suppose I have the following text:

```
__This_is__ a __test__
```

Using two underscores for denoting italics. So I expect `This_is` and `test` to be italicized. The logic dictates that any text between two consecutive double underscores should be italicized, including any other number of underscores that may be there. I've got:

```
__([^_]+)__
```

What is the equivalent of "not two consecutive underscores" in group 1? Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

An option would be to match two underscores:

```
__
```

Then make a negative look ahead to see if theres no two underscores ahead of the current position:

```
__(?!__)
```

if that is not the case, match any character:

```
__(?!__).
```

and repeat the previous one or more times:

```
__((?!__).)+
```

and finally match another two underscores:

```
__((?!__).)+__
```

which is the final solution.

A little demo:

```
<?php
$text = '__This_is__ a __test__';
preg_match_all('/__(?:(?!__).)+__/', $text, $matches);
print_r($matches);
?>
```

produces:

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [0] => __This_is__
            [1] => __test__
        )

)
```

as can be seen on [Ideone](http://ideone.com/mTxn0).

### EDIT

Note that I used a non-capturing group in my demo, otherwise the output would have looked like this:

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [0] => __This_is__
            [1] => __test__
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [0] => s
            [1] => t
        )

)
```

i.e. the last character matched by `((?!__).)` would have been captured in group 1.

More about groups, see: http://www.regular-expressions.info/brackets.html

Comment: Thanks! But it seems the code differs from the deduced regex. What is the extra `?:` in `__(?:(?!__).)+__` for?

Comment: `(?:...)` is a non-capturing group whereas `(...)` captures the contents for later re-use. Since you're not reusing the repeated element, you can use the former construct and gain a little efficiency.

Comment: @qsmith, ah, I see @Tim beat me to the punch. Anyway, see my EDIT.

Answer (score 1):

```
$text = '__This_is__ a __test__';
preg_match_all('/(__([\w]+)__)/', $text, $matches);
print_r($matches);
```

http://ideone.com/uHJCC

Comment: In case you read my previous comment, never mind me: I had a brain-fart! :) +1